# How to start new powershell window from powershell with properly resolved parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that wraps opening ten new powershell windows and in each a powershell script `MyScript.ps1` is called with dynamic arguments. My C:\temp\SystemWrapper.ps1 looks like this at the moment:

```
$system = "1"
$version = "1.0.0.0"
Write-Host("Triggering system $system / 10 with version $version")
start powershell { Write-Host('Starting system $system / 10 with version $version'); C:\temp\MyScript.ps1 $system $version; Read-Host}
```

System wrapper window output:

```
Triggering system 1 / 10 with version 1.0.0.0
```

Second powershell window output:

```
Starting system $system/10 with version $version
C:\temp\myScript.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'system'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:86
+ ... stem/10 with version $version'); C:\temp\myScript.ps1 $system $versio ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [myScript.ps1], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,myScript.ps1
```

The values for the variables in the SystemWrapper.ps1 do not resolve properly for starting the second powershell window and seem to be handed over as raw strings `$system` and `$version`.

The second powershell windows should look like this:

```
Starting system 1 / 10 with version 1.0.0.0
#... and the rest of the script with the arguments $system and $version properly resolved as input parameter
```

How can I achieve the expected output in the second powershell window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin your MyScript script with a `param()` block like this:

```
param (
    $System,
    $Version
)
```

Then start it using

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoLogo -NoExit -File `"C:\temp\MyScript.ps1`" -System $system -Version $version"
```